# Apps not recognizing Bluetooth presence (especially the mic)

Tags: bluetooth, audio, bluetooth-pairing, audio-recording

I have a good BT headset. It pairs without issue to my phone which has stock Android 7.0. Audio plays fine through the BT headset but for some reason the mic function is not properly recognized. I tested with Easy Voice Recorder. When I switch to record to with BT in that app, it says it can't recognize BT device. But it is clearly recording through BT (I left the phone in one room, and went to another room and whispered into my BT and it recorded it fine).
Any ideas what's going on here? I can live with this functionality in this app, but I use another app called TextNow (for VOIP calling) and it also doesn't recognize the BT and there's no workaround there.

- Phone: Moto G5
- Stock OS: Android 7.0
- BT headset: LG HBS-A100 Active Plus

I've noticed this behavior on other phones as well. Could it be something to do with the headset? I don't really know where to start with troubleshooting.